# Allocator with dense and sparse pointers - what's going on?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

i'm trying to write a handle allocator in C++.  this allocator would "handle" (hue hue hue) the allocation of handles for referencing assets (such as textures, uniforms, etc) in a game engine.  for instance, inside a function for creating a texture, the handle allocator would be called to create a TextureHandle.  when the texture was destroyed, the handle allocator would free the TextureHandle.

i'm reading through the source of [BX](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bx), a library that includes a handle allocator just for this purpose - it's the base library of the popular library [BGFX](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx), a cross-platform abstraction over different rendering APIs.

before i start explaining what's baffling me, let me first outline what this class essentially looks like:

```
class HandleAllocator {
  public:

  constructor, destructor
  getters: getNumHandles, getMaxHandles
  u16 alloc();
  void free(u16 handle);
  bool isValid(u16 handle) const;
  void reset();

  private:

  u16* getDensePointer() const;
  u16* getSparsePointer() const;
  u16  _numHandles;
  u16  _maxHandles;
}
```

here's what getDensePointer() looks like:

```
u8* ptr = (u8*)reinterpret_cast<const u8*>(this);
return (u16*)&ptr[sizeof(HandleAlloc)];
```

as far as i understand it, this function is returning a pointer to the end of the class in memory, although i don't understand why the **this** pointer is first cast to a uint8_t* before being dereferenced and used with the array-index operator on the next line.

here's what's weird to me.  the constructor calls the reset() function, which looks like this.

```
_numHandles = 0;
u16* dense = getDensePointer();
for(u16 ii=0, num = _maxHandles; ii < num; ++ii) {
  dense[ii] = ii;
}
```

if getDensePointer returns a pointer to the end of the class in memory, how is it safe to be writing to memory beyond the end of the class in this for loop?  how do i know this isn't stomping on something stored adjacent to it?

i'm a total noob, i realize the answer to this is probably obvious and betrays a total lack of knowledge on my part, but go easy on me..

Comment: Look at where an instance of this class is created. I predict the code there allocates a large chunk of memory, then uses placement `new` to construct an instance of `HandleAllocator` at the start of it. The class then uses an area of memory right after itself as a scratch space. In other words, the memory layout is essentially `struct { HandleAllocator alloc; u16  scratch[someSize];}` and `getDensePointer()` retrieves `&scratch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, ask yourself why pointers have a type. In the end, they are just variables that are meant to store memory addresses. Any variable with a range large enough to store all possible memory addresses could do. They what is the difference between, let's say, `int*` and `u8*`?

The difference is the way operations are performed on them. Besides dereferencing, which is another story, pointer arithmetic is also involved. Let's take the following declarations: `int *p; u8 *u;`. Now, `p+2`, in order to have sense, will return the address at p+8 (the address of the second integer, if you'd like) while u+2 would return the address of u+2 (since u8 has a size of 1).

Now, sizeof gives you the size of the type in bytes. You want to move sizeof(x) bytes, so you need to index the array (or do pointer arithmetic, they are equivalent here) on a byte-sized data type. And that's why you cast it to `u8`.

Now, for the second question,

> how do i know this isn't stomping on something stored adjacent to it?

simply by making sure nothing is there. This is done during the creation of the handler. For example, if you have:

```
HandleAllocator *h = new HandleAllocator[3]
```

you can freely call reset on h[0] and have 2 handlers worth of memory to play with. Without more details, it's hard to tell the exact way this excess memory is allocated and what's its purpose.

Comment: thank you so much!  cleared up everything i was wondering about and now pointer types of different sizes make perfect sense.